# Empty GET response after clicking button on web page

Tags: python, django

I stucked with next (**search.html**):

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="GET">

        {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="row">
           <input placeholder="Word" style="width:50%;height:15px;border:1px solid #de272b" type="text" value="" name="textbox1" size="1"/>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
           <input placeholder="Phone" style="width:50%;height:15px;border:1px solid #de272b" type="text" value="" name="textbox2" size="1"/>
       </div>
       <input style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;width:300px;height:30px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" name="button">
    </form>
```

This is search form in my template.

**views.py:**

```
def search_engine(request):

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="user",
                         passwd="123456",
                         db="test", charset="utf8")
    cur = db.cursor()
    q = request.GET.get("button", None)

    if q:
        cur.callproc('search', {'Id': 2})
        data = cur.fetchall()
        request.GET.get('textbox1')
        request.GET.get('textbox2')
        return render(request,'search.html', {'result': data})

    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

Mysql procedure works fine, problem is in django.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^search', search_engine, name="search")
```

After clicking button I recieves nothing. Adding any data in "if" statement and sending to render - no effect.

Comment: what do you get when you do `print(request.GET)` in your view?

Comment: exactly after print(request.GET): <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['LZG6js1ZIvVTSbGVjsyC6u3NhzDJz6HRXms9DhDIbx2VDyq7NzrRNbZ2qBPVWuNv'], 'textbox1': ['fds'], 'textbox2': ['sd'], 'button': ['Search']}>

Comment: So what do you actually want to achieve in this?
on clicking submit do you want the same data to come back with results?
I didn't see `result` variable usage in your template